# Best practices for upgrading static pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We have deployed etcd of k8s using static pod, it's 3 of them. We want to upgrade pod to define some labels and readiness probe for them. I have searched but found no questions/article mentioned. So I'd like to know the best practice for upgrading static pod.

For example, I found modifying yaml file directly may result pod unscheduled for a long time, maybe I should remove the old file and create a new file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate the pod if you want to define readiness probe for it, for labels an edit should suffice.

Following error is thrown by Kubernetes if editing readinessProbe:

```
# * spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363057/499839

Have you considered using DaemonSets? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Comment: I'm aware of DaemonSets, but since I'm deploying etcd used by k8s, so it seems impossible to deploy etcd using DaemonSets.